# Error while loading Rdata file in R

Tags: r

I used the following command to load an Rdata file:

```
xk <- load("sarima_data.Rdata")
plot(xk)
```

The following Errors occur :

> Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
>
> In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
> 2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>
> 3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

How to resolve this issue in R?

Comment: Can you show `summary(xk)`?

Comment: > summary(xk)

   Length     Class      Mode 

        1 character character

Comment: What does `print(xk)` return?

Comment: > print(xk)
[1] "yk"

Comment: So the variable `xk` only contains the character `"xk"` which you cannot plot of course... (I guess your data is wrong or damaged)

Comment: Christoph, after you've asked me to print(xk), since it returned yk, i tried to plot(yk) and it works! Thanks a lot!